# Remove overlaps from list of timestamps

Tags: excel, vba

I have start and end timestamps of subsequent occurrences and I want to remove overlaps from them. The entries are sorted in ascending order of start time.

This is my code:

```
Sub check()
    Dim i As Integer    
    For i = 2 To 12   
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value > ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then    
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp    
            Cells(i + 1, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp    
        Else:    
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value > ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then    
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp    
                Cells(i, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp    
            End If    
        End If    
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Input data:

```
Start_time      end_time
6/13/2018 19:16 6/13/2018 19:17
6/13/2018 19:18 6/13/2018 19:20
6/13/2018 19:21 6/13/2018 19:23
6/13/2018 19:22 6/13/2018 19:24
6/13/2018 19:25 6/13/2018 19:28
6/13/2018 19:26 6/13/2018 19:27
6/13/2018 19:29 6/13/2018 19:31
6/14/2018 19:30 6/14/2018 19:32
6/15/2018 19:33 6/14/2018 19:36
6/16/2018 19:38 6/15/2018 19:40
6/17/2018 19:39 6/16/2018 19:42
```

Desired output:

```
6/13/2018 19:16 6/13/2018 19:17
6/13/2018 19:18 6/13/2018 19:20
6/13/2018 19:21 6/13/2018 19:24
6/13/2018 19:25 6/13/2018 19:28
6/13/2018 19:29 6/14/2018 19:32
6/15/2018 19:33 6/14/2018 19:36
6/16/2018 19:38 6/16/2018 19:42
```

Actual result my code gives:

```
6/13/2018 19:16 6/13/2018 19:17
6/13/2018 19:18 6/13/2018 19:20
6/13/2018 19:21 6/13/2018 19:24
6/13/2018 19:25 6/13/2018 19:28
6/13/2018 19:29 6/13/2018 19:31
6/14/2018 19:30 6/14/2018 19:32
6/15/2018 19:33 6/14/2018 19:36
6/16/2018 19:38 6/15/2018 19:40
6/17/2018 19:39 6/16/2018 19:42
```

Can someone please help debug my code?

Comment: Whenever you're deleting rows it's best to work from the bottom to the top of the list...

Comment: I may be wrong, but this doesn't look like you are getting rid of overlaps, simply look at the last row of your input and the Start is clearly a day later than the end time, and on your desired output you get rid of that? You have at least the last three rows where Start-Time is later than the End-Time, you should look at that to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, but I found your code very confusing to read so I re-wrote it a little to make it easier (for me):

```
Sub check_rewrite()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim thisrow_enddate As Range, nextrow_enddate As Range, nextrow_startdate As Range

    With ActiveSheet

        For i = 2 To 12

            Set thisrow_enddate = .Cells(i, 2)
            Set nextrow_enddate = .Cells(i + 1, 2)
            Set nextrow_startdate = .Cells(i + 1, 1)

            If thisrow_enddate > nextrow_enddate Then
                nextrow_enddate.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                nextrow_startdate.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            ElseIf thisrow_enddate > nextrow_startdate Then
                nextrow_startdate.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                thisrow_enddate.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

It does the same thing in the same way, but when debugging it I found `nextrow_startdate` a lot more meaningful than `ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value`.

When I ran the code, I did indeed get the results you are seeing and I attempted to step through the code to see what was happening and why. When I did, I noticed that you have some unusual dating in your example data:

```
6/13/2018 19:29 6/13/2018 19:31    <- attempted overlap from here...
6/14/2018 19:30 6/14/2018 19:32    <- ...to here but it is not due to the DAY

6/15/2018 19:33 6/14/2018 19:36    <- your end-date is after your start date here
```

If these dates you provide are actually correct, then I see no way to get the desired output without re-writing the code to ignore the date element of each cell.

I'm hoping though, that these are errors - probably caused by auto-filling the columns. If you correct the dates (for instance, to all be 13th June) - the code (both mine and yours) does indeed result in your desired output (forgiving the dates).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are Right! My test data was wrong. My code actually does what it was intended to do. Since I sort my data with the start time never does my actual data look like my test data. Thank you!